# How to get access to the confluent registry schema id used by kafka producer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I have a kafka producer that uses confluent schema registry. I know that there is an algorithm based on which the `KafkaAvroSerializer` finds out the matching schemaId from the confluent schema registry (or gets it after registering the schema) so that it includes it as part of the wire format.

Is there a way that I can access the specific schema id that is added by the producer to the messages?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CachedSchemaRegistryClient` class to do HTTP lookups to get an ID.

Otherwise, you can use ByteBuffer

```java
Serializer s = new KafkaAvroSerializer();
s.configure(...); // give properties like registry url 
byte[] value = s.serialize(record); // example

ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(value);
bb.get(); // magic byte
int schemaId = bb.getInt();
```